# Delphi Solution for data replication between two remote sites loosely connected

Tags: database, delphi, database-replication

I'm using Delphi XE4 Architect (Delphi Xe3 is ok as well)
I need to find a smart solution to the following problem
and I would like to use one of these frameworks: kbmMW or RemOjects SDK / DataAbstract or RealThinClient

Currently I have an application using a very simple MSSQL database on a site A that is used by users of a site B through the remote desktop.
The application sometimes needs to show some pictures and also view some PDF, but it is mostly text data entry.

There is no particular reason for me to use MSSQL,
but it is a database that I found already active and populated and I have not built it myself. 
And now, it would be complicated to change it.
(Database is not important, not using specific features nor stored procedures nor triggers)

Users of the Site B are connected to the A site via a network connection very slow 
and occasionally the connection is not available for a few hours and up to one day (this is the major problem).
The situation of the connection, unfortunately, can not be improved for various reasons.

The database is quite simple has many tables that hardly ever change,
about ten instead undergo daily updates and potentially they may be subject to competing changes.

Mainly the records of these tables contain data that are locked in update
from a single user to edit some fields and then he saves releasing the lock.

I would like to get something very different to optimize performance.

Users of the A site have higher priority, they are more important, because the A site is the headquarters.

I would like to have a copy of the database at Site A to Site B,
so that users of site B can work in local, much faster without using the remote desktop connecting to the site A.
The RDP protocol is not very optimized and in any case if the connection is absent, users could not work.

Synchronize and update databases lock records between the two databases may not be a big problem.

Basically when a user of the Site B acquires edit a record in the database B,
obviously a user of the site A should not be able to modify the same record on the database of the site A. 
This should also work in the opposite direction of course.

My big problem is figuring out how handling to the best the situation that occurs
when the connection between B and A is not available for some hours. (And transaction/events is increasing on site B).
Events on Site A have generally priority (on collision) on events on Site B.

Users of the Site B must be able to continue working. 
When the connection becomes active, the changes should be sent to the database at Site A.
Obviously this can result in conflicts, but the changes made on the record
possibly by users B can be discarded or it can be done under the supervision of a selective merge
and approval record by record user of the site B.

Well, I hope the scenario is almost explained clearly.

Additional infos:

- DB schema is very simple, only tables, no triggers, stored procedure. So I can build one as example but imagine 10 tables that can be updated in concurrency.
- DB is used by a desktop app of sales departement, so it contains most secret data.
- Remote connection is typically max 512Kbit, but the main problem here is that the connection sometimes may be not active
  and user on remote site must work anyway. THis is the main focus.
- Total data of daily updates could be at max 10 Mb, compressed, only for DB connections. There are some other data synchronized
  on the same connection but they are not part of this job.
- I don't want to use specific MSSQL tools or services (replications or so on), because DB could change in future.

Thanks

Comment: So to summerize, you're looking to build a server side application on Site A that would have constant access to the database and on Site B you want a client application that only queries data from the database but can ocassionally inject it back and update the database? About right?

Comment: Yes, mostly as Shunty explained in your answer

Answer (score 0):

We do almost exactly this using a Delphi client app, a kbmMW based Delphi server app, MSSQL database (though it used to work quite happily on on DBISAM database too).

We have some tables that only the head office site users are allowed to modify. The smaller tables are transferred in their entirety each time there is a "merge". The larger tables and the transaction type tables all have a date added and/or a date modified field and only those records that have been changed or added in the last 3 weeks or so (configurable) are transferred. This means sites can still update to the latest data even if they have been disconnected for quite some time - we used to have clients in remote places on dubious dial up lines!

We only run the merge routines once or twice a day but it would work equally well on an hourly basis or other time schedule.

At given times of day each site (including head office) "export" their changed/new records to files (eg client dataset tables or similar). These are then zipped up by the application and placed in an "outgoing" folder. The zip file is named based on the location id, date, time etc. The files are transferred by some external means eg via FTP / file share / email etc etc. Each branch office sends/transfers its data files to head office and head office transfers its data to each branch. The files are transferred by whatever means to an "incoming" folder.

On a regular basis (eg hourly) each location does a check on the incoming folder to see if there is anything new for it to import. If so it adds all the new records, branch locations overwrite the head-office data tables with the new ones and edited records are merged in "somehow". This is the tricky bit. The easiest policy is "head office wins" so all edits are accepted unless there is a conflict in which case the head office version wins. Alternatively you could use "last edited wins" - but then you need to make sure clocks are in sync across locations. The other option is to add conflicting records to some form of "suspense" status and let an end user decide at some point in the future. We do this on one data set. Whichever conflict method you choose you need to record each decision in some form of log table and prompt an administrative level user to check occasionally.

When the head office imports data or when data is added at the head office then a field is set to indicate the data is part of the master data. When branches add data this field is empty to indicate it has yet to reach the master set. This helps when branches export their data as they can include all data that doesn't have this field set.

We have found that you can't run the merge interactively as you'll end up never getting any work done and you won't be able to run the merge at night etc. It needs to be fully automated with the ability for an admin user to make adjustments at some point after the fact.

We've been running this approach for several years now on multi-site operations and once it settled down it has worked pretty much flawlessly. With 2 export/import schedules per day we have found the branch offices run perfectly well and are only ever missing less than a days worth of transactions. Works well in our scenario where we don't often have conflicts. Exported data is in the region of 5-10MB which zips up plenty small enough.

Primary keys are vital! We use a GUID and it hasn't let us down yet.

The choice of database server and n-tier framework are, actually, irrelevant. It's the process that matters here.

> Basically when a user of the Site B acquires edit a record in the database B, obviously a user of the site A should not be able to modify the same record on the database of the site A. This should also work in the opposite direction of course.

I can't see how you're ever going to make this bit work reliably if both sites have their own copy of the database and you're allowing for dropped/non-existent inter-site connections on occasion.

Comment: Exactly! That's I would like to do! I'd like to use kbmMW, your work would be almost perfect for me!

Comment: >Basically when a user of the Site B acquires edit a record in the >database B, obviously a user of the site A should not be able to >modify the same record on the database of the site A. This should >also work in the opposite direction of course. Only in case there is a connection active, via a callbak, push, event message or something notification.

Comment: But if the lock is only there when a connection is available then you can't rely on "safe" editing and will have to code for the alternative  and leave it to your conflict resolution. So it seems a lot of wasted effort to code the callback etc when it's not going to be 100% reliable anyway. What if you have a connection when you set the lock but the connection drops before you have released the lock?

Comment: Yes, obviusly you are right, it must be manually Unlocked by users on site A (There will be a message like, "Record XXXX is locked by user YYY on date .... Do you want to unlock it?". A brutal action, but if the record if locked by N hours, presumably safe without make a telephone call.

Comment: Hello Shunty, can you provide a concept working project with kbmMW using a example general DB schema? (also with some rewards of course :) )

Comment: Sorry, I really don't have time for that. It's not exactly a trivial piece of work. kbmMW has good samples that are worth following - although, as I said, it's more about the process on the database side rather than the middle tier framework.